# I am trying to make Selenium google search click, but it always gives me an error

Tags: python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="Driver\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'No thanks')]").click()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[@name='account']"))
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[title='Search']").send_keys("google")
```

above is the script which I am trying to write. I am getting no no such element exception pasted the error message below.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(text(),'No thanks')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.81)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00E878B3+2193587]
```

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I try the link "https://www.google.com".

It's only show the "No thanks" button at the first time.

Maybe you can use "http://www.google.com" to search, and remove the line as below.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'No thanks')]").click()
```

BTW, if you want to do a search function. I think [google search API](https://github.com/abenassi/Google-Search-API) is other method.